# Do you need the double bed to get married + kids in story of seasons?

Tags: story-of-seasons

I'm planning on gettting married, but I'm not sure if it works on harvest moon rules where you have to have a double bed to get married.
Also, can you have kids? I'm playing as a guy so can my companion have a kid? And if so how many?

Comment: Please limit yourself to one question per question in the future.

Comment: Is this question for the original *Story of Seasons*, or the sequel *Story of Seasons: Trio of Towns*?

Answer (score 1):

Your house needs to be upgraded to include a double bed, yes.

The Big Farm House is the upgrade you need to be at. The blueprint for the house upgrade will be at Gunther's shop for 100,000 G after you build the Upgraded House (or 70,000 G if you are playing in Seedling mode). The Big Farm House requires 60 Lumber, 60 Stone, 10 Glass Stone, and 7 Emerald.

The house comes with a double bed inside of it. You can change the style of the double bed if you want, but you don't need to have a specific double bed style to get married.

source and more reading for marriage [here](http://fogu.com/sos1/villagers/marriage/)

As for your second question, yes. There are kids in the game, The type of wedding you choose to have determines how quickly they show up (more expensive wedding = quicker kids). The kids are always twins(1 boy, 1 girl). They don't do much(like help around the farm... lazy bums), but there is a few fun events that they trigger.

and source and more reading about kids [here](http://fogu.com/sos1/villagers/the-two-children.php)